# Short text classification

Tags: nlp, classification, message

I am about to start a project where my final goal is to classify short texts into classes: "may be interested in visiting place X" : "not interested or neutral". Place is described by set of keywords (e.g. meals or types of miles like "chinese food"). So ideally I need some approach to model desire of user based on short text analysis - and then classify based on a desire score or desire probability - is there any state-of-the-art in this field ? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

This problem is exactly the same as sentiment analysis of texts. But, instead of the traditional binary classification, you seem to have a "neutral" opinion. State-of-the-art in sentiment analysis is highly domain-dependent. Techniques that have excelled in classifying movies do not perform as well on commercial products, for example.

Additionally, even the feature-selection is highly domain-dependent. For example, unigrams work well for movie review classification, but a combination of unigrams and bigrams perform better for classifying twitter texts.

My best advice is to "play around" with different features. Since you are looking at short texts, twitter is probably a good motivational example. I would start with unigrams and bigrams as my features. The exact algorithm is not very important. SVM usually performs very well with correct parameter tuning. Use a small amount of held-out data for tuning these parameters before experimenting on bigger datasets.

The more interesting portion of this problem is the ranking! A "purity score" has been recently used for this purpose in the following papers (and I'd say they are pretty state-of-the-art):

- Sentiment summarization: evaluating and learning user preferences. Lerman, Blair-Goldensohn and McDonald. EACL. 2009.
- The viability of web-derived polarity lexicons. Velikovich, Blair-Goldensohn, Hannan and McDonald. NAACL. 2010.